# return this from a generic method generalized with <T extends TestClass>

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors, return-type

Why can't I do this in Java:

```
public class TestClass {

    public <T extends TestClass> T test(){
        return this; // error here
    }
}
```

As I understand, `this` will always be an instance of some class that extends `TestClass`, so why the code above is not allowed by compiler? Even if I will extend the `TestClass` then type of `this` will fit `extends TestClass` anyway. I get the following error:

> Error:(4, 16) java: incompatible types: TestClass cannot be converted
>   to T

Comment: Perhaps you could give us some more information about the context (what you want to achieve), so when can suggest alternative ways instead of only explaining why your approach doesn't work.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff It is kind of a research question. Roughly speaking I investigate *simulated self-type* idiom from Effective Java by Joshua Bloch (Item 2) and methods chaining in particular.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say you have `SubTestClass extends TestClass`, and you write:

```
TestClass instance = new TestClass();
SubTestClass result = instance.test();
```

This is legal regarding the signature of your `test()` class, although nonsense (1). The compiler will deduce that `T` is the class `SubTestClass`. And then it's clear that a `TestClass` instance isn't `instanceof SubTestClass`. So with legal usage of your `test()` method, returning `this` can produce type mismatches, and that's what the compiler tells you.

With your `test()` signature, it's impossible to return anything other than `null`, because `null` is the only value you can assign to a variable of unknown type.

Let me explain that last claim (asked for in comments): The implementation of the `test()` method has to return some value that matches the `T` type, and the concrete type (deduced from the call situation to be `SubTestClass`) isn't deducible to the method - there's nothing in the arguments or in the instance fields where it can read out the requirement to return a `SubTestClass` in this situation. In another call situation, it might be required to return `AnotherSubTestClass`, and there's no way it can tell the first from the second situation.

If you return `this` (with `(T)` casting to make it pass the compiler), it will fail either in the first or in the second or in both situations. So you can't do that without high risk of failure.

The only value that you can successfully assign to both a `SubTestClass` and a `AnotherSubTestClass` variables, is the `null` value. So that's the only value you can safely return from a method with such a signature.

(1) Having a generic method where the generic type can't be deduced from the parameters, but instead only from the expected result type, can hardly work - how should the method know what the caller expects?

Comment: Looks close, but it is not true that I can't return anything other than `null`. I can cast `this` to `T`.

Comment: Try it yourself ;-). With casting this to T, it still is a TestInstance, and not a SubTestInstance. Casting doesn't change the instance, it's just a developer's promise that the instance has the correct type, and this promise doesn't hold.

Comment: I mean, it will of course fail in runtime, but compile is ok.

Comment: I consider failing in runtime far worse. All the compiler checks are there to find potential runtime problems as early as possible.

Comment: Sure, runtime fail is far worse. I just can't understand your phrase properly: *impossible to return anything other than null*. Your (1) notice is quite valuable, but I am still ponder it.

Answer (score -1):

you are misunderstanding something:

> As I understand, `this` will always be an instance of some class that extends TestClass

That's not true, `this` can be an instance of the `TestClass` itself. And that's why the compiler broke. In order to fix it you should cast `this` to `T`:

```
return (T) this;
```

**Edit 01:**

By the way, if you want to do something like this, I would also recommend you to add one of this two options to prevent RuntimeError:

- set the `TestClass` as an abstract class
- make sure that `this` is not an instance of the `TestClass`, you can do that with something like this: `this.getClass().equals(TestClass.class)`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Now you've moved the problem from the compiler to a runtime error.

Answer (score -1):

"this" represents the class "TestClass",because TestClass is T's superClass，superClass cannot be converted to subClass,but you can try Forced type conversion,or Set the return type  to "TestClass".

```
public <T extends TestClass> T test() {
    return (T)this;
}
```

edit 01：
forced cast is wrong,it It may cause runtime errors.

Comment: What do you mean by "Forced type conversion"?

Comment: It's a cast, and this is *broken*.  If you cast this you're basically ignoring the very sane and reasonable type advice that the compiler is trying to provide for you and you move this to a runtime error.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff forced cast.